# Using "-" to exclude some variables when regressing

Tags: r, logistic-regression, predict

Using the *Weekly* Dataset from ISLR pacakge on R:

```
> head(Weekly)
  Year   Lag1   Lag2   Lag3   Lag4   Lag5    Volume  Today Direction
1 1990  0.816  1.572 -3.936 -0.229 -3.484 0.1549760 -0.270      Down
2 1990 -0.270  0.816  1.572 -3.936 -0.229 0.1485740 -2.576      Down
3 1990 -2.576 -0.270  0.816  1.572 -3.936 0.1598375  3.514        Up
4 1990  3.514 -2.576 -0.270  0.816  1.572 0.1616300  0.712        Up
5 1990  0.712  3.514 -2.576 -0.270  0.816 0.1537280  1.178        Up
6 1990  1.178  0.712  3.514 -2.576 -0.270 0.1544440 -1.372      Down
```

Trying to use Logistic Regression to regress Direction on *all Lag variables and Volume*, and tried to use the "all except" shortcut on R to exlcude Year and Today:

```
logregall <- glm(Direction ~ . - Today - Year, 
                 family=binomial(link='logit'), data = Weekly)
```

But when I try to use this same object to make predictions, R somehow gives the error that I have forgotten to include Year in the 'newdata' dataframe despite not including Year:

```
dataforpred <- Weekly[,2:7]
preds <- predict(object = logregall, newdata = dataforpred, type = "response")

> preds <- predict(object = logregall, newdata = dataforpred, type = "response")
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Year' not found
```

But when I regress by keying all variables manually, I get a fitted object that works for predict()

```
logregall2 <- glm(Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag3 + Lag4 + Lag5 + Volume, 
                  family=binomial(link='logit'), data = Weekly)
preds <- predict(object = logregall2, newdata = dataforpred, type = "response")

> head(preds)
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
0.6086249 0.6010314 0.5875699 0.4816416 0.6169013 0.5684190
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Please share data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can copy/paste for resting.

Comment: @MrFlick Sorry, I presumed that the 5 rows/ being able to get the dataset via the package sufficed to get the main idea of the problem. Should I use dput for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the package but I can replicate the error with mtcars dataset. I believe the reason is because you specified to remove some columns with `-`, so what the function does is to remove those columns first and then performs the prediction. It gets error out since it could not find those columns in the `newdata`.

Therefore, the solution is to manually assign arbitrary values to the columns.

```
fit <- glm(vs~. -mpg-cyl,data=mtcars, 
           family=binomial(link='logit'))

dataforpred <- mtcars[,c(3:7,9:11)]

preds <- predict(object = fit, newdata = dataforpred, type = "response")
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'cyl' not found

#solution
dataforpred2 <- dataforpred%>%
  mutate(mpg=NA_real_,
         cyl=NA_real_)
preds2 <- predict(object = fit, newdata = dataforpred2, type = "response")

> preds2[1:5]
           1            2            3            4            5 
2.220446e-16 1.081386e-11 1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 2.220446e-16
```

Comment: so NA_real_ is just an arbitrary placeholder value so that mpg and cyl are effectively useless in the model despite being included?

Comment: thank you nevertheless!

Comment: Right. This seems to be the only method if you have ```-``` in the formula.

Comment: Actually, another way is to remove those redundant columns before fitting the model. Then you don't need to specify ```-```.